# SQL - join 2 tables despite one column having an underscore

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to combine 2 tables (Table A and Table B) based on 2 columns with the same data except there is a '_'.

For example:

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| IE03 | IE_03 |
| IE04 | IE_04 |

Is there any way to join the 2 tables in SQL based on columns ID1 and ID2 regardless of the underscore?

Comment: the logic depends on your DBMS which should be tagged with sql tags

Comment: Ideally you should be aiming to fix your design. You could inject the underscore (`_`) into the one that doesn't have it, or you could remove it from the one that does, however, neither such statements would be SARGable. If the 2 values are meant to be equal, then they should be equal, and thus one of your tables needs to be updated appropriately and then a `FOREIGN KEY` created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; you'll have to remove the underscore. In Oracle, we use `REPLACE` function. For example:

```
SQL> select replace('IE_03', '_', '') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
IE03

SQL>
```

In other databases (I don't know which one you use as you didn't specify it), I believe they offer something similar.

So:

```
select *
from table_1 a join table_2 b on a.id1 = replace(b.id2, '_', '')
```